# ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 4 and 224 for '{{node Equal}} = Equal[T=DT_FLOAT, incompatible_shape_error=true]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying o build a neural network, but I am facing problems fitting that.

Data shapes:

X_train = (555, 224, 224, 3)

X_test = (99, 224, 224, 3)

y_train = (555, 4)

y_test = (99, 4)

X_val = (116, 224, 224, 3)

y_val = (116, 4)

Code snippet:

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, AveragePooling2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Concatenate, Input
from keras import Model

# Defining model input
input_ = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))

# Defining first parallel layer
in_1 = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_)
conv_1 = BatchNormalization()(in_1)
conv_1 = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(3, 3))(conv_1)

# Defining second parallel layer
in_2 = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_)
conv_2 = BatchNormalization()(in_2)
conv_2 = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(3, 3))(conv_2)

# Defining third parallel layer
in_3 = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_)
conv_3 = BatchNormalization()(in_3)
conv_3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(3, 3))(conv_3)

# Defining fourth parallel layer
in_4 = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(9, 9), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_)
conv_4 = BatchNormalization()(in_4)
conv_4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(3, 3))(conv_4)

# Concatenating layers
concat = Concatenate()([conv_1, conv_2, conv_3, conv_4])
flat = Flatten()(concat)
out = Dense(units=4, activation='softmax')(flat)

# tell the model what cost and optimization method to use
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
model.compile(
  optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.00001),
  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
  metrics=['accuracy']
)


model1 = model.fit(X_train,
                        y_train,
                        validation_data = (X_val, y_val),
                        epochs = 100,
                        batch_size=batch_size
                        # callbacks=[es_callback]
                        )
```

error:
**ValueError: Dimensions must be equal but are 4 and 224 for '{{node Equal}} = Equal[T=DT_FLOAT, incompatible_shape_error=true](IteratorGetNext:1, Cast_1)' with input shapes: [?,4], [?,224,224].**

Comment: This code is working fine when I replicate the same in Google Colab. Please check this attached [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/c591816e766028f15a06fc2fb36d9043/75119478.ipynb) as a reference for the same. Could you also help me to know if you are building the model for different outputs (4) as I can see in the label dataset shape is (555,4) or for one output with 4 categories?